# Python name of latest folder created in a directory

Tags: python, directory

I am new to python and have to play with directories.
Can someone help me with it?
I have to know a path with newly created folder. A new temp folder is generated by my code in which some files are copied. I have to know the path of this folder , but folder name is random , so I want to fetch the folder name of latest created folder.
What shall i do?

Comment: How are you creating this folder with a random name? There are a few ways to do that, so it's pretty hard to help you if you don't show us your code...

Comment: I have an application that create it . I have to test the file created in newly created tempxxxxx folder insise C:\TempDir. So I was thinking if i could get the name of temp folder bu finding latest created folder in C:\TempDir

Comment: I think i can refer this ... but dont know exactly how?  newest = max(os.listdir('.'), key = os.path.getctime)

Comment: You _could_ use functions to find the name of the newest folder & file in TempDir, but that's not a great technique, since other programs can be creating stuff there. The usual way is to keep track of the random name that the OS gives you when you create the file or folder. You said in the question that `A new temp folder is generated by my code` and `I have an application that create it`. So show us this code and we'll help you fix it so that it keeps track of the random file & folder names.

Comment: I am a tester and do not have access to any code. application code is in C moreoever . I have to create test code in python! Can i find in python the name of the latest created folder in a directory(C:\TempDir) ?

Comment: What functions are you refering above?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
import os

directory = '.'  # current dir
folders = os.walk(directory).next()[1]
creation_times = [(folder, os.path.getctime(folder)) for folder in folders]
creation_times.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])  # sort by creation time
```

Then you can pick the last element of this list:

```
most_recent = creation_times[-1][0]
```

Comment: I do not have next() to use. Error message says:AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'                                    When i try using "__next__" prefixed and postfixed by 2 underscroes  it gave different error message: File "<pyshell#78>", line 1, in <module>
    folders = os.walk(directory).__next__()[1]
StopIteration                                                            I am trying to run it through python IDLE and verison is 3.4.1

Comment: @user1726783, Yes, in Python 3 you would use `next(os.walk(directory))[1]`. Please  mark the question as answered if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bad practice to fetch the latest folder created because some other application may create a folder right before you fetch the latest folder, but if you really want to try it out the code what elyase has demonstrated is fine.